# Automating Instagram login using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete, instagram

(I am trying to access username but no success can anybody help me how to fix this issue?)

```
# Definig e-mail & password
email = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']")
# password = driver.find_element(By.NAME,  "password")
# Assining e-mail & password
with open(r"E:\datams\user.txt") as myuser:
    username = myuser.read().replace('\n', '')
email.send_keys(username)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the problem or `error` you are receiving, from which line atleast ??

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), It is not only fair to those helping you in their spare time, but it also increases chances to receive an answer.

Comment: I am trying to access the username of my profile on Instagram using selenium using css selector class with aria-label but its giving me error

Comment: or if you have any other process of logging in Instagram using python